# Does angular load routes with ajax?

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent page that has a portion inside that changes when the url changes(i.e. /#partial-view1, /#partial-view2 ) does angular load those using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chrome (or firebug), inspect element, and open the network tab.  You'll see if it a fires an ajax call or not.  Routes typically do since they are fetching the templateUrl to download the html template they must render.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your promises do.

If they run an ajax call, then yes, they load with ajax.